# Displaying item in tasks form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath

**I would like to display item informations in my tasks form.**

I think i need to use **data connection** in Infopath.

I can display  **all my items in my form** , but i want to display **item who matches with my task.**

How can i do this ?

Thanks in advance,

E Guidez

PS: i tried to improve my English.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use a data connection to receive data. If you name it e.g. *ReceiveData*, you can display these information in text boxes.

Set a default value (right click the text box) and add your field to display. Make sure you select the field under *ReceiveData*, and do not set a field from another data connection.

The magic happens under the button "Filter Data". Here you add a filter like *task ID is equal to 'select a field'*. It depends on your scenario what you have to select here (keep an eye on the right data connection). Easiest would propably be to filter according to a unique title. You need a unique key which links your item to a task.

Comment: I probably do something wrong.
I selected "Nom de famille" in my data source connection "Arrivée".
When i open controle propreties, i got this:
http://i.imgur.com/BoApmn0.png

Comment: Can you edit and further explain in your question? External images are blocked at where I am.

Comment: In control propreties, all fields are "grey tint", i can't add or modify things.
I have : Links , default value and Validation

Comment: What kind of controls do you have? For text boxes it is normal that Binding is greyed out. What you need is to change the default value. For that click the formula button and then add your fields in the way described.

Comment: It's a text box, but i can't change default value, and i can't click on the formula button .

Comment: That's weird, I never had that. What kind of list are you using? How did you open the InfoPath form?

Comment: I'm using a custom list. In SharePoint Designer 2013, i clic on my workflow for viewing this general settings.
I have on my screen: Workflow Information, Settings, Customization Starts Options and Forms.
I select my form under forms and i click on open in the ribbon.
This is open my form directly in Infopath 2013

Comment: I do not have SPD2013, so I can't reproduce your steps. But I assume the same happens, if you open the form via the Customize Form Button in the web interface?

Comment: How can i open my task form from SharePoint website ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27484/discussion-between-eguidez-and-wheeler).